# Ordered logit with missing output values (does it meet the proportional odds assumpion?)

Tags: ordinal-data, biostatistics, odds-ratio, odds, ordered-logit

My dataset has **3 features** and **21 rows**.
The Output Y have 11 distinct values in an **ordinal scale** from 1 to 10.
The 3 features are real numbers, in a range between 150 to 350.
More precisely the output is the answer given by 21 patients to a question.
The question is made after an experiment where a few bio-signals are measured.
I'm trying to build a model to forecast the level of sickness (I don't have to be specific about the kind of sickness), given 3 different bio-signal measurements. The answer of the question is used as the output for the model.

I'm considering to use the ordered logit method for this task.
Questions:

- How can I know if my dataset meet the proportional odds assumptions?
- Some of the number in the questionnaire have never been used as an answer (for example nobody answered 4, 6 or 10). Is this by itself going to make the proportional odds assumption not valid?
- If the proportional odds assumption is not met, would is have sense to reduce the output from 11 distinct values to 3 or 4, grouping the answer which are "close" between each other?

Final question/consideration:

- I don't understand the sense of the proportional odds assumption. In my case I'm measuring bio-signal of patients who almost always will declare a level of sickness higher than 4 or 5. The proportional odds assumption says that at least the half of the patients should be in the group of people who declared a level equal to 0, since $log\frac{p0}{p1+p2+...+p10} = 0$ right?
- The previous formula comes from the Wikipedia's page of the ordered logit ([Ordered_logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit)), but over there they consider $p_{i}$ as the number of members in the population i. Does this fit also in my case? Or I should interpret $p_{i}$ as the probability of answering i? (which would be may be the same)

Comment: You have 21 observations?

Comment: Yes ... unfortunately sometime is really hard to find real patients to make measurement ... this is the best we could do so far

Comment: There is no way an ordered logit model is going to give you reliable results in this case. In the most basic of models, you will be estimating 11 - 1 threshold parameters and 3 regression parameters with 21 data points.

Comment: Ok ... what if I reduce the possible output values, for example to low,  medium, high ? Would such a reduction be useful? Could I use ordered logit then ?    ... I also have another dataset with 105 rows, but the problems which I specified in the question persist.

Comment: With a dataset this size, I would stick to visualizations. Others can weigh in with their opinions.